# PHP not picking up Ajax POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send some data from a HTML page to a PHP page.

I've made sure that the dataString is actually sending text by using console log.

It shows up as `pid=12345`

My AJAX is:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'Task2.php',
    data: {pid:res[1]},
  success: function(data) {
    //alert(data);
      $("#container").html(data); 
      console.log( data );
 }
});
```

My PHP is:

```
$temp = $_POST['pid'];
```

The PHP isn't picking it up even if I do it manually by going to `myserver/Task2.php?pid=12345`.

Comment: How can you tell if the PHP is picking it up or not? Your PHP doesn't output anything!

Comment: (Your approach of going to the server and putting the data in the query string will make a GET request and put the data in `$_GET`. That is quite unlike what the JavaScript is doing).

Comment: @Quentin from the php page Notice: Undefined index: pid

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem — https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPcyoSZRhFEYqOwe8FB2aBq552u-XcNQWc — whatever it is, it isn't in the code you have shared with us.

Comment: @Quentin The code works now but the problem im having is that when the html page loads , its shows the php error undefined index on it before it loads the correct data . how do i fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for something like this...

```
var dataString = res[1];
console.log( 'pid=' + dataString );

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'Task2.php',
  data: { pid: dataString },
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

by specifying data: { pid:dataString } in your ajax call, your telling it to POST the dataString value as a form element named "pid".  You chould be able to pick it up PHP side with $_POST['pid'];

**EDIT**

Here is a full, working example.  All self contained in a single PHP file.  Should help you get it sorted out.  The reason for the isset($_GET['testing']) at the top is because I'm using the same file in the ajax call too.  Just fyi...

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['testing'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
            echo $_POST['pid'];
        } else {
            echo 'not set';
        }
    }
    else
    {
?>
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="test()">test</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        var dataString = "pid=testing123";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php?testing",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</html>
<?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: While that is best practise, constructing the URL encoded data string manually will still work.

Comment: @Quentin, but if he constructs it manually does jquery still pass it over with pid as a POST value?  Or does it come through at that point as GET

Comment: Yes. If you say type POST then it is a POST request.

Comment: @Phil Thanks . The code works now but the problem im having is that when the html page loads , its shows the php error undefined index on it before it loads the correct data . how do i fix this

Comment: @JohnyChew can you post your updated code?  When I run the code from my post above with error reporting turned on I get no errors at all.  If you start your PHP page off with $temp = $_POST['pid'], you will get the undefined index error because the "pid" has not been posted yet.  Which is why I would use if (isset($_POST['pid'])) { // do stuff }

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {pid: res[1]}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'Task2.php',
    data: data,
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

You cannot read from `$_POST` When using `$_GET` params (?pid=12345)

Comment: i get Notice: Undefined index: pid

Comment: is it possible that you have an htaccess that redirect you to the page again and then you loose the post data? this answer will work on a normal post.

Comment: this is in the htaccess - Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteRule (.*)Release(.*)\.js $1Compressed$2\.jsgz [L]
RewriteRule (.*)Release(.*)\.data $1Compressed$2\.datagz [L]
RewriteRule (.*)Release(.*)\.mem $1Compressed$2\.memgz [L]
RewriteRule (.*)Release(.*)\.unity3d $1Compressed$2\.unity3dgz [L]
AddEncoding gzip .jsgz
AddEncoding gzip .datagz
AddEncoding gzip .memgz
AddEncoding gzip .unity3dgz

Answer (score 0):

Data should be a hash:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'Task2.php',
    data: {pid:res[1]},,
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

And in php don't mix $_GET with $_POST. http://example.com/a.php?q=1 => $_GET['q'], but the above ajax code will send it to $_POST['pid']

Comment: While that is best practise, constructing the URL encoded data string manually will still work.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: pid